# EF Core 7 - Include only items which are not deleted

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core, expression

In EF Core 7, I am able to filter included collections like

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(x => x.Roles.Where(y => y.IsDeleted == false)).ToList();
```

I would like to make an extension, which simplify this include to this:

```
var users = _context.Users.Include(x => x.Roles, true).ToList();
```

where true means withoutDeleted.

So, I need to merge two expressions, In my case

```
Expression<Func<IDbEntityDelete, bool>> expression1 = x => !x.IsDeleted;
Expression<Func<User,ICollection<Role>>> expression2 = x => x.Roles;
```

First one is constant expression and second one is an expression comming as argument in my extension.

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TCollection> Include<TEntity, TCollection>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, TCollection>> navigationExpression, bool withoutDeleted) where TEntity : class, IDbEntityDelete
{

}
```

Could you please help me to Combine navigationExpression with expression1?

So the result lambda is exactly x => x.Roles.Where(y => y.IsDeleted == false)?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some interface for classes like `ISoftDelete`. If yes, it is easy.

Comment: Ah, I see `IDbEntityDelete`. Will prepare solution tomorrow or on Monday.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv great, thank you! I am pretty frustated with this as nothing worked, what I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple extension implementation should add soft delete filter for `Include`:

```cs
public static class IncludeExtensions
{
    public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable<TItem>> Include<TEntity, TItem>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query, 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TItem>>> navigationExpression, 
        bool withoutDeleted
    ) 
        where TEntity : class
        where TItem : class, IDbEntityDelete
    {
        if (!withoutDeleted)
        {
            return query.Include(navigationExpression);
        }

        // let the compiler to generate filter stuff.
        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TItem>, IEnumerable<TItem>>> filterTemplate = q => q.Where(e => !e.IsDeleted);
        
        // replacing template parameter with navigationExpression
        var filterBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterTemplate.Parameters[0], navigationExpression.Body, filterTemplate.Body);
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TItem>>>(filterBody, navigationExpression.Parameters);

        return query.Include(filterLambda);
    }
}
```

Comment: good job Svyatoslav Danyliv, you are the ReplacingExpressionVisitor 's master.

Comment: cool, simple and it's working fine! Thank you :-)